# Error while loading pipe delimited data from flat file into a SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

I am looking at existing SSIS package.

I download the package from source control. Change connection managers to point to my local dev environment.

Task is to read from Flat file and to load into the SQL Server database.

File is a `|` delimited flat file. In connection manager, Header row delimiter has set as {LF}.

While executing task, I ran into several error and one of that is

> curr user file [2]] Error: Data conversion failed. The data conversion for column "customfield_storeid" returned status value 4 and status text "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page.".

I looked into the connection manager, column has set to string[DT_STR] and 'OutputColumnWidth' to 50.

In my database table, that column is of type `varchar(50)`. So it seems there is not anything wrong.

If I could change error output to ignore truncation error, it would not show error. But I do not want to change what has previously set for the package.

How do I  resolve it?

Comment: Start with the actual text of the error message. Are any of the rows in the customfield_storied column longer than 50 characters? Or do any of them include Unicode or non-printing characters?

Comment: value for the column is empty . That is '| |'

Comment: This error message is almost always related to the underlying data. Since you’re only importing one row, would it be possible to post the file? I’m wondering if you’re counting fields correctly (an error I’ve made), because an empty string won’t generate a truncation issue.

Comment: one of a line has this data 8888|77777|1531|0|0|""Pop""|Lopez|myemail@example.com|
is it because of two double quote ?

Comment: Which column represents customfield_storeid? None of those columns are empty.

Comment: There's another thing to look for. An unquoted pipe in your data set will cause your fields to shift and the remaining fields get jammed into your last column

Comment: sir, I created new package, and load the same file to my local db, It did not throw any error. Package which I had been working on was from source control.